# Trim and Replace functions fail to remove spacing with INTO statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to remove some leading/trailing spaces from a column in a database using the LTRIM and RTRIM function in MSSQL. When I simply select the data, the trim function works correctly:

```
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(mycolumn))
    FROM mytable
```

However, when I write the same query to a table with an INTO statement, the trailing spaces remain in the data. I'm having the exact same issue with the replace function when attempting to move tabs and indents. What am I missing?

Comment: Is the target column defined as a char() instead of a varchar()?

Comment: might have a tab somewhere in there. Try replacing  CHAR(13) , CHAR(10) , and  CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) with '' and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you trim the data but you are using a select INTO the datatype in the new table will be same datatype as the source table. I am guessing you have char in your source table? Convert the column when you select it to varchar and the trailing spaces will go away.

```
SELECT convert(varchar(50), LTRIM(RTRIM(mycolumn)))
INTO MyNewTable
FROM mytable
```

Comment: This ended up solving my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you update the table first to clean up before doing the INTO statements:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = LTRIM(RTRIM(mycolumn))

SELECT mycolumn
INTO MyNewTable
FROM mytable
```